# Limit of $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(4x)}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I was trying to solve this problem, but couldn't figure it out. The solution goes like this:

[image: http://www.tkiryl.com/Calculus/Problems/Section%201.4/Calculating%20Limits/Solutions/Calc_S_59.png (I don't have the reputation to post the image)]

I don't understand the first step. Why is the limit multiplied by $\frac{4x}{5x}$? and $\frac{5}{4}$ ?

Comment: It is a clever way of writing $1$: $$1 = 1\cdot1\cdot1= {4\over4}\cdot{5\over5}\cdot{x\over x} = {4x\over 4} \cdot {5\over 5x} = {4x\over5x} \cdot {5\over 4}.$$ When you multiply by $1$, you don't change the original expression, but doing so allows us to make some algebraic manipulations that help us involve other identities. Namely: $$\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x} = 1$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was hard for me to see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(4x)}=$

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(5x)\cdot5x\cdot4x}{\sin(4x)\cdot5x\cdot4x}=$

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(5x)\cdot4x\cdot5x}{5x\cdot\sin(4x)\cdot4x}=$

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(5x)}{5x}\cdot\frac{4x}{\sin(4x)}\cdot\frac{5x}{4x}\right)=$

$\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(5x)}{5x}\right)\cdot\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{4x}{\sin(4x)}\right)\cdot\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{5x}{4x}\right)=$

$\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(5x)}{5x}\right)\cdot\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{4x}{\sin(4x)}\right)\cdot\left(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{5}{4}\right)=$

$1\cdot1\cdot\frac54=$

$\frac54$

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could use [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule):

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(4x)}$=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\sin(5x)}{\frac{d}{dx}\sin(4x)}$=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{5\cos(5x)}{4\cos(4x)}=\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: This is correct, but L'Hopital's Rule may be a tool not within OP's reach yet.

Comment: This is incorrect according to Wikipedia, since the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is computed using  L'Hopital's rule, so you've essentially fallen into a chicken-egg paradox.

Comment: @barakmanos what do you mean?

Comment: @StephanCasey: I'm trying to find the Wikipedia page which describes this oxymoron...

Comment: @StephanCasey: Sorry, I am unable to find the English version of this Wikipedia page. Perhaps it is wrong, but it says that if you're using the geometric definition of Sine, then in order to prove that the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$, you need to rely on the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$. Hence, any attempt to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ by relying on the fact that the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ is essentially a chicken-egg paradox.

Comment: @barakmanos but we are not trying to prove that with the L'Hopitals method. We are proving the result in a different way but of course there is no problem with relying on this fact because the OP's method relies on it as well?

Comment: @StephanCasey: I'm not really sure, I'm just (kinda) quoting what I understand from reading this on Wikipedia. Of course, I might be misunderstanding things here.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(4x)}$$

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(5x)}{x} . \frac{x}{\sin(4x)}$$

$$∵\lim \limits_{\theta \to 0}\frac{ \sin(a\theta)}{\theta}=a$$

$$=\frac54$$

Answer (score 0):

They were using the Squeeze theorem but I don't think it is necessary (https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/limits-from-equations-dc/squeeze-theorem-dc/v/proof-lim-sin-x-x)

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin5x}{\sin4x}$$

$$= \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin5x}{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin4x}$$

where $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin4x$ not equal to $0$

but it is equal to zero so we can't do this so we can use L'Hopitals Rule where you differentiate top and bottom. We will be using chain rule here as well because $\frac{d}{dx}\sin5x = \cos5x \times \frac{d}{dx}5x = 5\cos 5x$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin5x}{\sin4x}$$

$$=^{L'H} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5\cos5x}{4\cos4x}$$

Now just substitute zero

$$= \frac{5\cos(5(0))}{4\cos(4(0))}$$

$$=\frac{5(1)}{4(1)}$$

$$=\frac{5}{4}$$